# Laravel: array inside array shows Trying to access array offset on value of type int

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10

I was trying to print array inside a foreach loop in following way:

```
@foreach($response['results'] as $row)
    <tr>
       <td>
         @foreach($row['status'] as $r)
            Status-  {{$r['groupName']}}   //  it shows above error on this line
         @endforeach
       </td>
       <td>{{$row['from'] - $row['sentAt']}}</td>
       <td>{{$row['to'] - $row['doneAt']}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I have checked in every response and I have got status value on each response. Here is my array response:

```
"results" => array:14 [▼
      0 => array:13 [▼
        "messageSegments" => array:3 [▶]
        "sentAt" => "2024-02-23T04:41:01.881Z"
        "doneAt" => "2024-02-23T04:41:03.267Z"
        "mmsCount" => 3
        "mccMnc" => "310260"
        "price" => array:2 [▶]
        "status" => array:5 [▼
          "groupId" => 3
          "groupName" => "DELIVERED"
          "id" => 5
          "name" => "DELIVERED_TO_HANDSET"
          "description" => "Message delivered to handset"
        ]
        "error" => array:5 [▼
          "groupId" => 0
          "groupName" => "OK"
          "id" => 0
          "name" => "NO_ERROR"
          "description" => "No Error"
        ]
        "applicationId" => "default"
      ]
      1 => array:13 [▶]
      2 => array:14 [▶]
      3 => array:14 [▶]
```

But it shows following error :

> Trying to access array offset on value of type int

What could be possible error behind that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review the basics about arrays, you don't have to loop over your index since it's just a multidimensional array. You can access what directly by:

```
$row['status']['groupName']
```

Answer (score 0):

While you loop your status array, your first element is the `groupId` with the value of `3`, an integer. When you try to do `$r['groupName']` where `$r` is an integer, you will end up having the issue you mentioned in the question. Instead:

```
@foreach($response['results'] as $row)
    <tr>
       <td>
            Status-  {{$row['status']['groupName']}}   //  it shows above error on this line
       </td>
       <td>{{$row['from'] - $row['sentAt']}}</td>
       <td>{{$row['to'] - $row['doneAt']}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```